# Smarter way to include Row Names into multiple formulas

Tags: r

I have multiple data sets to call on, and present in a few places. The code works fine, but its a laborious task to copy/paste each variable and mutation to get the result. There must be an easier way to incorporate rownames + variable to create some sort of loop!

I am simply copy/pasting the same variables and changing the name to the next row.

```
row1Mapped <- sum(cnx$row1Connect =="Mapped", na.rm = TRUE)
row2Mapped <- sum(cnx$row2Connect =="Mapped", na.rm = TRUE)
row3Mapped <- sum(cnx$row3Connect =="Mapped", na.rm = TRUE)
row4Mapped <- sum(cnx$row4Connect =="Mapped", na.rm = TRUE)

main <- main %>%
  mutate(Mapped = ifelse(Bank == "row1", row1Mapped,
                    ifelse(Bank == "row2", row2Mapped, 
                     ifelse(Bank == "row3", row3Mapped, NA))))
```

Everything works, I however would like to be more efficient!

Comment: Try `colSums(cnx == 'Mapped', na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Hi Sotos - how would I then call on each summed column in the next mutation? I created variables of each so I could do so in the above example.

Comment: Please share a reproducible example along with the expected output in order to be able to help you further